Using slurm array jobs
I have a jobscript that runs a certain python script with arguments provided with argparsing. I know that when I want to run this job, I will almost always want to submit not just one job, but several in parallel with different values of one particular argument. I have read several articles on using slurm arrays for this, by setting for instance:
#SBATCH --array=1-10 at the top of the jobscript, and then accessing the values of the array using $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID in the call the python script. However, I can't seem to find a way to make the array run over any arbitrary array of numbers. For a concrete example, say I would like to use the values [0.1, 0.75, 3, 25.5, 50]. The numbers can always be increasing, but aren't necessarily related mathematically in any other way. I know I could write a separate file and read these values in based on the row number of that file, but that seems like overkill.
How can I use #SBATCH --array with arbitrary and non-integer array values?

I'm afraid the job numbers need to be integers (though they can be non-consecutive --array=3,5,17,22. If you want different jobs to use different floats (like 0.1), you'll need to use the integers to look up float values in a config file or hard coded list.

Ah I see thank you. Pardon the basic question, but is there a way to do arithmetic within the jobscript? In the example above, say I just set --array=10,75,300,255,5000, and then can I just divide by 100 when I pass that number in the call to the python script?

Usually, there exist a maximum value for the job array (you can check your particular value by checking your particular SLURM config scontrol show config), so you probably won't be able to use an integer as high as you need. Your best bet is using an intermediate array that translates the integers of the job array to the floats you need, as @damienfrancois should in his answer.

The easiest way is to use an intermediate Bash array:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH ...
#SBATCH --array=0-4

ARGS=(0.1 0.75 3 25.5 50)

./script.py ${ARGS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}

This will effectively submit a 5-job array where each job will run script.py with the value in $ARGS whose index is the $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

Great thank you!
